# Come out of Edit mode using javascript- kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid with inline editing .
I need, on click of checkbox which is present in the grid i have to make row as editable and come out of edit mode.
To make kendo grid as editable i am using this code

```
var grid = $("#GridID").data("kendoGrid");  
var gridDataArray = grid.dataSource._data;      
var ctrl = event.target;   
var row = $(this).parents('tr');  
var index = row.index();  
grid.editRow(row);
```

so the selected row is in edit Mode. Now, i need to get out of edit mode using javascript/JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`saveRow`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-saveRow) or [`cancelRow`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-cancelRow), depending on whether you want to save the user changes or not.

On a side note, use the official [`data`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data) method

```
grid.dataSource.data()
```

instead of internal fields:

```
grid.dataSource._data
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you very well. Please clarify what exactly are you trying to do.